# Updated MediaWiki and now get dialog "this is a test 2, do not panic" on every page

Tags: testing, dialog, mediawiki

I updated our MediaWiki server from 1.13 to 1.26 and everything appears to be working OK.  Except on EVERY page, a dialog pops up that says "this is a test 2, do not panic".  Even if you check the box to not allow this page to create further dialogs, it appears on any page you click through.  Any thoughts?

Comment: It's an internal wiki for development.  Sorry, no link.  I've searched the entire directory recursively for any of the text to no avail.

Comment: http://i128.photobucket.com/albums/p191/mcseforsale/wiki_dialog_zps4ttd67ag.png

Comment: What extensions are installed? Also, do you have anything in `MediaWiki:Common.js`? There is no message like that in MediaWiki, so this is from somewhere else.

Comment: The only extensions being loaded in LocalSettings.php are SyntaxHighlight_GeSHi, InputBox, SimpleSecurity and PdfBook.  The 2 former ones are using the standard wfLoadExtension while PdfBook and SimpleSecurity are using the require_once statements.    Where do I find MediaWiki:Common.js?

Comment: see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Interface/JavaScript

Comment: Excellent.  I found the call, but I still don't know why it was there.  The previous admin of this wiki was a bit...umm...interesting.  The call is this:w.loader.using( ['mediawiki.util', 'mediawiki.notify', 'jquery.client'], function () {
/* Begin of mw.loader.using callback */
alert('this is a test 2, do not panic');

Comment: OK.  Apparently, the admin before me put this in.  I was able to comment out the alert and it's now working as expected.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There was extraneous java code in the MediaWiki:Common.js.  From the search bar (as admin) type in Mediawiki:Common.js and edit that to see any java that is executing for all pages.  Thanks leo!